# What is a regular expression to catch all git commit footer/trailer lines in git log output?

Tags: python, regex, git, formatting

I am writing a script to remove git commit tags (eg `Signed-off-by:, Reviewed-by:`) from each git commit message.  Currently the script is in python.  Right now I have a very simple `re.match("Signed-off-by:", line)` check.  But I think there should be more elegant solution using regular expression.

I am assuming that a footer will begins with [more words separating by -]: For example

`Bug:, Issue:, Reviewed-by:, Tested-by:, Ack-by:, Suggested-by:, Signed-off-by:`

The pattern should ignore case.  I need help coming up with a solution using regular expression for this.  I also want to learn more about RE, what is a good starting point?

The actual python script is here https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/#/c/33213/2/tools/gitlog2asciidoc.py

You could also comment on the script if you sign up for an account.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to do this to start with? You know that you can customize the output of "git log" command to start with? See "git help log" for formatting strings. Example:  git log --pretty=format:"The author of %h was %an, %ar%nThe title was >>%s<<%n"

Comment: @Joakim I don’t see any formatting options in `git log` that allows you to keep the message minus the trailers (`git version 2.39.2`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> def match_commit(s):
    r = re.compile(r'((\w+*)+\w+:)')
    return re.match(r, s) is not None

>>> match_commit("Signed-off-by:")
True
>>> match_commit("Signed-off+by:")
False
>>> match_commit("Signed--by:")
False
>>> match_commit("Bug:")
True
>>> match_commit("Bug-:")
False
```

The 1st group `(\w+-)*` captures 0 to any repetitions of patterns "word + '-'", the last one `\w+:` looks for the last word + ':'.

Comment: Thanks, but this logic doesn't support case when the footer line has one word. (eg Bug:, Issue:). Could you update the regex to handle the case?

Comment: Oh, you're right ! I just have to use repetitor `*` (0 or more repetitions) instead of `+` (1 or more) for the 1st group - see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

While the regular expression approach would be nice and with just a flag you can ignore case, I think that in this case you can just use `startswith` to achieve the same goal:

```
prefixes = ['bug:', 'issue:', 'reviewed-by:', 'tested-by:',
            'ack-by:', 'suggested-by:', 'signed-off-by:']
...
lower_line = line.lower()
for prefix in prefixes:
    if lower_line.startswith(prefix):
        print 'prefix matched:', prefix
else:
    print 'no match found'
```

Comment: Thanks but this mean I have to change code every time I want to add more footer.

Comment: You can get the list of prefixes from a configuration file if you wish, so that you don't need to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice use case for `any`:

```
for line in logfile:
    if any(line.lower().startswith(prefix) for prefix in prefixes):
        print line
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m assuming that the original question was about removing all trailers.

> I am assuming that a footer will begins with [more words separating by -]:

From `man git-intepret-trailers`:

> Existing trailers are extracted from the input message by looking for a
> group of one or more lines that (i) is all trailers, or (ii) contains
> at least one Git-generated or user-configured trailer and consists of
> at least 25% trailers. The group must be preceded by one or more empty
> (or whitespace-only) lines. The group must either be at the end of the
> message or be the last non-whitespace lines before a line that starts
> with --- (followed by a space or the end of the line). Such three minus
> signs start the patch part of the message. See also --no-divider below.

(`git version 2.39.2`)

(I will ignore the “divider line” part since that is irrelevant for commit messages.)

That sounds too involved for a regex.

`git interpret-trailers` can already parse trailers for you. Done. Right? Not quite.

`git intepret-trailers` has the `--only-trailers` option, but not the dual `--whole-message-except-trailers` (or something). So it looks like we have to do some work.[1]

Get the whole commit message of a SHA1:

```
git log -1 --format='%s%n%n%b' 688ce90c53d7565f6f8e1d5e438b960620630448
```

In this example that would be:

```
Bug: bad documentation of commit conventions

It has come to my attention that some of our committers don’t know how
Signed-off-by: trailers are supposed to be used. Unacceptable! Let me
elucidate this in our docs.

Make haste!

Keywords: nitpicking
Cautioned-against-by: Victor Version Control <vvc@vcs.org>
Reviewed-by: Sophia Change My Mind <sophia@vcs.org>
Nacked-by: Hector Relaxed <h@vcs.org>
Yawned-at-by: Yellow Baggers <yelly@vcs.org>
```

I want to remove the five last lines.

We can use `grep --invert-match --fixed-strings`. The problem though is that we want to negatively match on multiple lines: keep only lines that don’t match this-or-that. We can do that with:

```
grep --invert-match --fixed-strings --regex='Keywords: nitpicking' […]
```

And we can build up that command using (*sigh*)… Bash.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

grep_command="grep --invert-match --fixed-strings "
trailers=$(git log -1 --format='%s%n%n%b' 688ce90c53d7565f6f8e1d5e438b960620630448 \
    | git interpret-trailers --only-trailers)

while IFS= read -r trailer; do
    # `--regex=<trailer>` to `grep` with single quote delimiters
    grep_command+=--regex=\'"$trailer"\'" "
done <<< "$trailers"

# `git log` reprise
git log -1 --format='%s%n%n%b' 688ce90c53d7565f6f8e1d5e438b960620630448 \
    | eval "$grep_command"
```

Output:

```
Bug: bad documentation of commit conventions

It has come to my attention that some of our committers don’t know how
Signed-off-by: trailers are supposed to be used. Unacceptable! Let me
elucidate this in our docs.

Make haste!
```

It seems this outputs one or two newlines extra at the end. I guess that can be postprocessed away.

#### Notes

1. `git log` supports formats like `%(trailer)` and `%b` (body), but seemingly not body-except-trailers.